# How to generate a PDF report out of robot framework

Tags: robotframework

Trying to get a PDF report automatically after the test completion. Would like to know if there is inbuilt keyword/support to get it done or I have to create a script to read the html file generated and convert it to PDF with custom format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Python library which converts HTML to PDF: `xhtml2pdf`

`pip install xhtml2pdf`

[PyPi Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/xhtml2pdf/)

Comment: I get an error: Opening Robot Framework report failed
• Verify that you have JavaScript enabled in your browser.
• Make sure you are using a modern enough browser. If using Internet Explorer, version 11 is required.
• Check are there messages in your browser's JavaScript error log. Please report the problem if you suspect you have encountered a bug.

Comment: Just google "Opening Robot Framework report failed"

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in feature to do this. Robot can generate xml and html output. For anything else, you'll have to supply your own tool to do the conversion.